# Assigning custom starting position on a website

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, position

I want to create a website scrolled vertically. The problem I have is that I want starting point on the website to be on the center. I guess I need to use JS for this, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently `outerHeight` is only supported in Firefox. How about this?

```
var winWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
var winHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
window.scrollTo(winWidth, winHeight / 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work on most browsers. **window.outerHeight** is the height of the entire content of the page. **window.scrollTo** scrolls the browser to the specified x and y coordinate.

```
window.scrollTo(0, window.outerHeight / 2);
```